# Battery percentage jumps erratically on an 8 month old Lenovo Y720 laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery

My laptop has been acting very strange the last few weeks. It is about 8 month old.

I have conservation mode turned on, which means it does not charge above 60%. However lately when I am using it, it will go down to about end thirties (like 39%) and suddenly begin to turn off, not turn off immediately but like when it goes into sleep mode. Then I plug in the charger and the battery is suddenly 0%, fully drained.

So it jumps from around 40% to 0% in an instant. Uptime is usually around 1 hour and 10 minutes on battery, where it normally would be above 2 and a half hours. If I only charge the battery to  something under 40%, like 15%, it will not turn off.

I have made a battery report in windows, notice how at the end today it is 37% then suddenly it turns off.
The report is very long so I took a picture of the important part.

[image: Report]

OBS:
The report also says that the design capacity is **57.000 mWh** and current capacity is **49.740 mWh**

Comment: Beyond specifics, if this is 8 months old and is still under manufacturer warranty, I would just get this repaired or exchanged. It sounds like it’s a case of a defective battery.

Comment: But isn't it strange it only just started to happen? It has been working fine for 8 months with no problems.

Comment: Yes, it is strange it only started to happen. When strange things like this happen, it means something is defective. And the behavior describes sounds like a defective battery. Do yourself a favor, the chances of you finding the one thing that caused this is slim to none. And you will only cause yourself headaches. Get this item repairer or exchanged under warranty and you will be in better shape.